# Check dataset is empty or not

Tags: c#, dataset

This is working for me just fine. With if checks if dataset is empty or not. If so, return null value. But is the check of dataset right way or should i do some other way?

```
 da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT project_id FROM project WHERE _small_project_id = '" + cb_small_project.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY NEWID()", conn);
 ds2 = new DataSet();
 da2.Fill(ds2);
 DataRow[] rowProject = dt2.Select();

 if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    cmd.Parameters["@_project_id"].Value = guidNull;
 else
    cmd.Parameters["@_project_id"].Value = rowProject[0]["project_id"];
```

Comment: I think you should check whether you have tables aswell

Comment: You mean something like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264554/how-to-check-empty-datatable ?

Comment: yes, just in case or rap it up in try,catch block, to prevent the code stop in case of exception

Comment: Or do you mean something like this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976473/how-to-test-if-a-dataset-is-empty>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In my opinion the 'right' way is to check both:

```
ds2.Tables.Count 

ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count
```

Comment: ds2.Tables.Count will give 1 even if the table has no data.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try check for:
`ds2.HasChanges()`
It should be true if any data has been added.
For further information check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325617%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bool` and return `true`. For all tables in `dataset`

```
bool IsEmpty(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    if (table.Rows.Count != 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This will throw exception if the data set is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me.... and won't give exception....

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
   if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
      table.Dispose();
```

Comment: dynamic solution

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if (((System.Data.InternalDataCollectionBase)(ds.Tables)).Count != 0)
{
}
else
{
}
```

above code will work